# I'm trying to create a trigger that, after creating a new record in the message table, read the count of each of the moods

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm new in postgresql so far, don't judge this strictly)
I have 2 tables: message, where records with the mood of different users are stored and the countMood table.
I'm trying to create a trigger that, after creating a new record in the message table, read the count of each of the moods (excelent, good, normal, not_good, bad) in the mood column from the message table and wrote these results into the second countMood table in the fields with these moods

these are my 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mood.message (
uuid uuid,
dt_create timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
dt_update timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
summary character varying,

mood character varying NOT NULL,
dt_log date,
author_create uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES shadows.users(uuid),
CONSTRAINT message_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mood.countedMood (
id SERIAL,
excellent int,
good int,
normal int,
not_good int
);
```

I tried to create a trigger that does the task I need

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_count_of_mood()
RETURNS trigger AS $$ BEGIN
UPDATE mood.countedMood
SET good = (SELECT COUNT(mood) FROM mood.message WHERE mood='GOOD'),
excellent = (SELECT COUNT(mood) FROM mood.message WHERE mood='EXCELLENT'),
normal = (SELECT COUNT(mood) FROM mood.message WHERE mood='NORMAL'),
not_good = (SELECT COUNT(mood) FROM mood.message WHERE mood='NOT_GOOD'),
bad = (SELECT COUNT(mood) FROM mood.message WHERE mood='BAD');
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER count_of_mood AFTER INSERT ON mood.message FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
update_count_of_mood();
```

But it does not cope with the task I need :(
If you can, please help with this problem.

Comment: In general, don't *store* that which can be computed. You're introducing an opportunity for the data to be *inconsistent*. Just pull the counts of moods from the `message` table on demand.

Comment: I just need to record the number of moods in another table. The task is precisely in this

Comment: BTW: a COUNT() is a (non negative) integer. Why do you want to store it in a varchar column?

Comment: You are right, it must be int, thanks for this ) But this does not solve the problem (

Comment: In what way does this not work?  I see a few inefficiencies and potential issues, like not handling updates or deletes, but what is the actual problem?  I also agree that this would be better as a view instead of a table updated by a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated you should not store easily calculated values. But depending on intended usage it would be better to create a VIEW that derived the counts when needed. You then select against the view instead of a table- but the query is identical. Further it is NOT necessary to select each mode but a single query with FILTER clauses. So:

```
create or replace view countedmood
                       ( good
                       , excellent
                       , normal
                       , not_good
                       , bad
                       ) 
  as select count(*) filter (where mood = 'GOOD')       
          , count(*) filter (where mood = 'EXCELLENT')    
          , count(*) filter (where mood = 'NORMAL')    
          , count(*) filter (where mood = 'NOT_GOOD')  
          , count(*) filter (where mood = 'BAD')    
       from  message ; 
       
select * from countedmood;
```

However, your statement that "record the number of moods in another table" makes it sound as though this is still another homework assignment where the instructor is requiring what would virtually never be implemented in a production application. You can essentially wrap the above query in a trigger function to populate the table. Note: Since the trigger will process the entire *Message* table there is no need to run *after each row* but just *after each statement*. See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) under Description.

> A trigger that is marked FOR EACH ROW is called once for every row
> that the operation modifies. For example, a DELETE that affects 10
> rows will cause any ON DELETE triggers on the target relation to be
> called 10 separate times, once for each deleted row. In contrast, a
> trigger that is marked FOR EACH STATEMENT only executes once for any
> given operation, regardless of how many rows it modifies (in
> particular, an operation that modifies zero rows will still result in
> the execution of any applicable FOR EACH STATEMENT triggers).

```
create table if not exists countedmood (
        id serial,                 -- WHY via description table will consist of 1 row.
        excellent int,
        good int,
        normal int,
        not_good int,
        bad int 
        );

create or replace 
function update_count_of_mood()
 returns trigger
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
   update countedMood
      set (good, excellent,normal,not_good,bad) =
          (select count(*) filter (where mood = 'GOOD')       
                , count(*) filter (where mood = 'EXCELLENT')    
                , count(*) filter (where mood = 'NORMAL')    
                , count(*) filter (where mood = 'NOT_GOOD')  
                , count(*) filter (where mood = 'BAD')    
             from  message
          )
    where id = 1; 
   
   return null; 
end; 
$$; 
 
create trigger count_of_mood
  after insert or update or delete 
     on message 
    for each statement                         --<< NOT FOR EACH ROW   
  execute procedure update_count_of_mood();
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=19d9cb0b2175766c0bfbd0ccdbea682c) of each method here.  
**A couple cautions:**

1. Do not use CamelCaseNames as Postgres will lower case them unless
   you put them in double quotes ("CamelCaseName") and then you must
   **always** use the double quotes. The convention is just not worth the trouble; forget the double quoter and you get an error. Instead just use Shake_Case_Names. Postgres will still lower case them Shake_Case_Name and
   shake_case_name are the same.
2. It is poor practice to declare a column name the same as its defined
   type (uuid uuid) or any other type or reserved word as a column
   name.